# subquery returning more than one row

Tags: sql-server

I know this is an old one but really stuck with this.

my sub proc goes domething liek this

```
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GETSOMETHING]
    --@OrgID nCHAR(10)
AS
    SELECT A.TENANT,
           A.LEASEE,
           A.SUITEE,
          A.TRADEDATES,
          A.Area,
        A.YTDSalesThisYr

FROM (

SELECT 

LEAS.TENTID AS TENANT,
LEAS.LEASID AS LEASEE,
SUIT.SUITID AS SUITEE,
TB_EMEA_CM_SHIS.TRADEDATE AS TRADEDATES,
(SELECT TOP 1 SQFT FROM SSQF INNER JOIN SUIT 
ON  (SSQF.BLDGID = SUIT.BLDGID AND SSQF.SUITID = SUIT.SUITID)
            WHERE SSQF.SQFTTYPE = 'NLA' AND SSQF.EFFDATE <=GETDATE() 
    ORDER BY SSQF.EFFDATE DESC)AS Area,

--SUM(TB_EMEA_CM_SHIS.AMOUNT) AS YTDSalesThisYr
(select SUM(A.AMOUNT) FROM TB_EMEA_CM_SHIS A  WHERE A.TRADEDATE BETWEEN (
SELECT DATEADD(month,-11,(select TOP 1 ENTITY.YEAREND + '01' from ENTITY 
INNER JOIN BLDG ON ENTITY.ENTITYID = BLDG.ENTITYID))
 )AND GETDATE()) as YTDSalesThisYr ---- i am getting the problem here..

FROM 

dbo.leas
         inner join TB_EMEA_CM_SHIS on 
            (TB_EMEA_CM_SHIS.LEASID = LEAS.LEASID
            AND TB_EMEA_CM_SHIS.BLDGID = LEAS.BLDGID)

INNER JOIN BLDG ON 
            BLDG.BLDGID = LEAS.BLDGID
INNER JOIN SUIT ON 
           (BLDG.BLDGID = SUIT.BLDGID 
           AND LEAS.SUITID = SUIT.SUITID)
INNER JOIN ENTITY ON 
             ENTITY.ENTITYID = BLDG.BLDGID

GROUP BY  TB_EMEA_CM_SHIS.LEASID, TB_EMEA_CM_SHIS.BLDGID,
TB_EMEA_CM_SHIS.TRADEDATE, LEAS.TENTID,LEAS.LEASID,SUIT.SUITID
)A
```

any ways to rewrite the sub query i have on top?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of SQL Server and what, precisely, is the problem?

Comment: It's entirely up to you how you format your own code, but if you post it and want some help on it, you may find that nicely formatted code snippets attract better attention.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe change:

```
SELECT DATEADD(month,-11,(select TOP 1 ENTITY.YEAREND ...
```

... to ...

```
SELECT TOP 1 DATEADD(month,-11,(select TOP 1 ENTITY.YEAREND ...
```

But all these `TOP 1`s everywhere point to something really messed up in your data model. If you use `TOP 1` without `ORDER BY`, which row do you expect?